# How to get VirtualBox to stop receiving keyboard input during installation of Android OS?

Tags: virtualbox, android-x86

I am currently installing android 5.1 os using VirtualBox,.

During the configuration at installing GRUB the VirtualBox will interpreting my keyboard input and print the key input at the black part.

How should I fix the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could press the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> /<kbd>Control</kbd> key on the right side of keyboard which should release keyboard input and mouse.

Comment: I know this function, but instead of releasing the keyboard input, I wish to get back to the GRUB configuration to continue the setup

Comment: you could always click in the middle of the VM machine to get input back into the Virtual machine to allow you to input characters into the VM

Comment: no, it wont give me back to the control of the configuration, it just capture my input and print it in the black part like the picture above

Comment: It seems like that Grub installer crashed/ran into a error and it is typing random characters if you want to emulate Android I would recommend a proper Android Emulator google has a Android Studio https://developer.android.com/studio you can google on how to emulate using the studio that x86 project was designed for 32/64 bit Processors but our PC's can emulate ARM easily.

Comment: Well I wish to access the wifi module of Android 5.1 which seems to be not available for using android emulator from android studio, but thank for your help, maybe I should go find other alternative way to do it

Comment: You might be able to use VMWare Workstation/Player which it might have a better chance of working VirtualBox is limited on capabilities of Video Memory and 3D Acceleration.